# saveFrames() of p5.Graphics

Tags: p5.js

[p5Graphics-saveFrames-image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGbnU.png)

Hi,
just programming processing some years.

and theseday i use p5js for web front-end developing(https://p5js.org)

then facing some error about saveFrames() on p5.Graphics

you can run sample code [here](https://editor.p5js.org/is2you2/sketches/SNirEo03n) or view below

```js
var pg;

function setup() {
let c = createCanvas(100, 100);
  pg=createGraphics(20,20);
  pg.background(0,255,0);
  background(255, 0, 0);
  pg.saveFrames('test','jpg',1,1,data=>{ // <<<< error occurred
    print('result',data)
  });
}
```

then console says,

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'elt' of undefined (sketch: line 8)

Yes, it acutally act about **Saving p5.Graphics panel as data_url**. like save PGraphics 
as image on Processing.

I wonder,

- is it possible to saving p5.Graphics
- or has it some way to fix **elt** err.
- or anyway to make p5.Graphics to image/data_url

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because graphics object has no such method, besides you need to **actually** render these frames in `draw()` method using your supplied *pg* variable somehow. Something like :

```
var pg;

function setup() {
  var c= createCanvas(200, 200);
  pg=createGraphics(150,150);
  pg.background(112, 0, 112);
  pg.ellipse(50, 50, 15, 45);
  saveFrames('test','jpg',1,1,data=>{print('result',data)});
}

function draw() {
  image(pg, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: great escape :D